# How to use google place api for specific city In PHP

Tags: php, google-places-api

I want to use google place api for specific city not world wide.

Currently i use below code

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&amp;libraries=places&amp;types=(locality)&amp;input={ahemdabad}" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function initialize() {
        var input = document.getElementById('searchTextField');
        var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>

<input id="searchTextField" type="text" size="50" placeholder="Enter a location" autocomplete="on">
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
<script>
function initialize() {
    var input = document.getElementById('searchTextField');
    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: map.getCenter(),
    map: map,
    title: "hi"
  });
}


</script>';
```

Comment: Hello, Saad. can you please specify how i can include in my above code.

Comment: i want to use only for search place from perticular city (eg. Mumbai, India) not the map.